# How to update xamarin forms subscription status from outside app when using in-app billing?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am developing Xamarin.Forms application which will be used for Android and iOS. It will have access to full functionality with a paid subscription (monthly or yearly). We plan to use in-app billing for implementing subscription on both stores.

There is a situation if a user buys the subscription in Android app and then wants to use iOS app or vice versa. In this situation, the user should be able to use the other platform app, because the user already purchased the subscription. We are planning to fix this issue by a back-end REST API. When the user purchase the app in android or iOS, we save the subscription details to our back-end. So once the user purchased the subscription in any platform, the user can use the app on other platform and multiple devices.

But if the user cancels the subscription from outside the app like apple or play store, how we can update the status on our back end? Because at this time the action happening on outside the app, so we can't update the status on back-end.

For example, If the user subscribed the app from play store and also using the iOS version. Then the user cancelling the subscription on play store. After that the user is not using the android app. At the same time the status is true on back end. So the user can use the iOS version without a subscription. How we can handle this type of situations?

We research a lot and find out we can call app store and play store via their APIs which will return the entire subscription details. So we will call it from the back end as a cron job and update the latest status once in a day. So if the user cancels the subscription from outside the app, that status will update on the back-end via cron job. Is this possible? Any other better solution for this kind of issues?

Comment: If you configure server to receive status change notifications, The app store sends your server a message whenever subscription status changes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/handling_subscriptions_billing So your server always knows the status. There might also be some way your server can ask both app stores about subscription status. So when user goes to use app, it could ask server to verify.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Is play store has a same feature to send our server a message whenever subscription status changes?

Comment: I found below blog. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher#subscriptions But in that there is no similar API to send our server a message whenever subscription status changes? Am I missed something?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve One more clarification that is not included in the question: Is auto-renewal is perform by App store and Play store, or do we need to create a cron job for that?

Comment: What happen If our server is down when the app store send a message? When server up, is the message will deliver to back end server?

Comment: [Google- Configure Real-time developer notifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#configure-rtdn). If your server remembers last log in, and on which device, when device change, or long time since you verified subscription, could query to verify. If your server goes down, I think query to be sure. I'd let them log in based on server's info, add them to a list to be verified. Verify as a separate server task. If then learn subscription expired, force app to a subscription renewal screen.